# Confusion Regarding createInsecureRfcommSocket()

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm aware that Android 2.3 has the methods: createInsecureRfcommSocket() and createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(). I've been searching for a way to exchange data between devices, both using my application, without the need for pairing/bonding and user confimation. Will these methods allow me to, say, connect to a brand new device never before paired, and exchange data without prompting the user in any way?

Thanks. I was unable to find a specific answer to this question elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The pairing process will still happen, except that if Devices are 2.1 and above, then the user will not be prompted for confirmation or for entering passkey during the pairing process. This is called using the "just works" model for pairing.

Comment: With the "just works" model, won't the user that initiated the pairing still be prompted to confirm that they desire to pair? I understand that the device being paired won't throw a dialog, but I'm wondering if the connecting device will.

Comment: Yes it might .. It is a good practice to ask the user for authorization - many devices might do it.

Comment: It might or it will? I can't test it at the moment, and I'm sure a definite answer would be very helpful to others.